Terraform failed to determine your intended installation method for remote
I am trying to use a Private Terraform Module Hosted on Bitbucket in GitHub Actions. But am getting the below error . What am I doing wrong?
/home/runner/work/_temp/b5ffd751-d41c-44d0-9df7-27542c871716/terraform-bin init

Initializing the backend...
Initializing modules...
╷
│ Error: Invalid module source address
│ 
│   on main.tf line 3, in module "lulapay_infrastructue":
│    3:   source = "git::https://<BITBUCKET_USERNAME>:<BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD>@bitbucket.org/lulalend/terraform-lula-infrastructure//terraform/stacks/lulapay"
│ 
│ Terraform failed to determine your intended installation method for remote
│ module package
│ "https://<BITBUCKET_USERNAME>:<BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD>@bitbucket.org/lulalend/terraform-lula-infrastructure".
│ 
│ If you intended this as a path relative to the current module, use
│ "./https://<BITBUCKET_USERNAME>:<BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD>@bitbucket.org/lulalend/terraform-lula-infrastructure"
│ instead. The "./" prefix indicates that the address is a relative
│ filesystem path.

main.tf
module "lulapay_infrastructue" {
  
  source = "git::https://<BITBUCKET_USERNAME>:<BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD>@bitbucket.org/lulalend/terraform-lula-infrastructure//terraform/stacks/lulapay"
  # other module inputs
}

Workflow:

name: Apply Terraform with Private Bitbucket Module

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - feature/**  # Apply Terraform on feature branches

jobs:
  terraform:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Set up Terraform
      uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2
      with:
        terraform_version: 1.8.5  # Specify the required Terraform version

    - name: Initialize Terraform
      working-directory: ./terraform/
      run: terraform init
      env:
        BITBUCKET_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.BITBUCKET_USERNAME }}
        BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD }}

    - name: Terraform Plan
      working-directory: ./terraform/
      run: terraform plan
      env:
        BITBUCKET_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.BITBUCKET_USERNAME }}
        BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD }}

    - name: Terraform Apply
      working-directory: ./terraform/
      run: terraform apply -auto-approve
      env:
        BITBUCKET_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.BITBUCKET_USERNAME }}
        BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD }}


This Issue is how am passing the  BITBUCKET_USERNAME and <BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD variables. How can I pass them as variables?
